# Flexible way to stop a few YouTube videos on Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

I have a few YouTube videos embed on Bootstrap overlay. The problem I have is that videos are still playing when I close it. I have these 2 solutions, but none of them work exactly as what I want.

Option 1:

```js
$(".modal-backdrop, .close").live("click", function() {
        $("iframe").attr("src", jQuery("iframe").attr("src"));
});
```

Issue of this is: when I close the overlay, all videos src changed to the same url. I saw someone using id, but it does not apply to $(".modal-backdrop"), does it?

Option 2:

```js
$(".modal-backdrop, .modal .close").live("click", function(){
   
var src = $(this).closest(".modal-dialog").find('iframe').attr('src');
   
$(this).closest(".modal-dialog").find('iframe').attr('src', '');
$(this).closest(".modal-dialog").find('iframe').attr('src', src);
});
```

This method does not apply to $(".modal-backdrop").

What is the way to achieve the result? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I got it working now.

```js
$(".modal-backdrop, .modal .close").live("click", function(){

  $("iframe").each(function() {
    var src = $(this).closest(".modal-dialog").find('iframe').attr('src');

    $(this).closest(".modal-dialog").find('iframe').attr('src', '');
    $(this).closest(".modal-dialog").find('iframe').attr('src', src);
  });

});
```